# Plotting vectors with uneven axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm struggling with a plot that I think is probably straightforward.

I'm running an algorithm with randomised inputs to find out how the error behaves as a function of the problem size, I need to plot a cumulative distribution at the end of it.

The structure of my code looks something like this:

```
for i=1:20:256
    for j=1:100
       MY ALGORITHM

    end
    errorThisTime = error
end
plot(errorThisTime)
```

I need to plot errorThisTime on an axis which goes from 0 to 256, but currently I can only get it to go up to 13 (the length of the errorThisTime vector).

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: You need to specify the `x`-coordinate. Currently it is using index (hence the max value of 13). Try this: `ThisTime = 1:20:256;` and then `plot(ThisTime, errorThisTime)`

Comment: but also surely you need something like `errorThisTime = [errorThisTime, error]`

Comment: @Dan I do do a step like that yes.

Answer (score 0):

As Schorsch suggested, you must include dummy x-variable carrying respective values. Plotting this with respect to `errorThisTime` vector should solve your problem.